# Changing font for keywords only in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

My question is pretty straightforward:
I've been looking for a way to change the font of some keywords (namely 'var' in JavaScript) in Sublime Text 3, but the solutions I've found on Google have only helped me change the color and font styling.

I've located the .tmTheme file of the theme I'm using, but since I'm not familiar with the markup, I get a little bit lost there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sublime doesn't support multiple fonts inside the same document so you can't have a completely different font for some symbols as opposed to others. The best you can is font style (bold/italic) that you already mentioned.

Comment: Ok. What a bummer... But cheers for the clarification!